# What's the best way to call an IBAction from with-in the code?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, ibaction

Say for instance I have an **IBAction** that is hooked up to a **UIButton** in interface builder.

```
- (IBAction)functionToBeCalled:(id)sender
{
   // do something here   

}
```

With-in my code, say for instance in another method, what is the best way to call that **IBAction**?

If I try to call it like this, I receive an error:

```
[self functionToBeCalled:];
```

But, if I try to call it like this (cheating a bit, I think), it works fine:

```
[self functionToBeCalled:0];
```

What is the proper way to call it properly?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The proper way is either:

```
- [self functionToBeCalled:nil]
```

To pass a nil sender, indicating that it wasn't called through the usual framework.

**OR**

```
- [self functionToBeCalled:self]
```

To pass yourself as the sender, which is also correct.

Which one to chose depends on what exactly the function does, and what it expects the sender to be.

Comment: What about passing the [sender tag] through programatically as well?

Comment: @Andy, You can pass in any NSView subclass to those methods. Well, actually, you can pass any NSObject whatsoever! (id) Is a generic type that can hold any parameter. Just make sure to send in what the IBAction expects to receive (usually a subclass of NSView)

Comment: @ZaidPathan that only works if your IBAction method is declared without a sender argument

Comment: This works but it is bad programming practice calling IBActions directly, because these functions are meant to be called by UI code. It is better to create a new function and call it from both places. In this way we will not add a dependency to UI related code.

Answer (score 11):

Semantically speaking, calling an `IBAction` should be triggered by UI events only (e.g. a button tap). If you need to run the same code from multiple places, then you can extract that code from the `IBAction` into a dedicated method, and call that method from both places:

```
- (IBAction)onButtonTap:(id)sender {
    [self doSomething];
}
```

This allows you to do extra logic based on the sender (perhaps you might assign the same action to multiple buttons and decide what to do based on the `sender` parameter). And also reduces the amount of code that you need to write in the `IBAction` (which keeps your controller implementation clean).